# Pointwise Mutual Information using spacy

Tags: spacy

So, I have been trying to play around with NLP recently and decided to work on a project involving **Emotional Analysis**. I have been following this particular research, http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~aan/research/paper/Emo_WI10.pdf.

But, for the sake of it I'm not able to understand how to implement **Sec.III part E** (PMI). I don't understand how to build my corpus, or what the window size is and how to determine what should be in them. I'm using **Spacy**, so getting information for the previous parts weren't hard. Any explanation or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of NLP methods for "meaning" or "semantic" similarity rely on the assumption that words that show up in similar places have similar meanings. For example, "I pet the dog" and "I pet the cat" - we maybe would assume dogs and cats have similar meaning.

spaCy uses something called embeddings which are trained based on thousands of documents (usually news articles or wikipedia pages) using that same idea. word2vec models delete a word from a sentence, look at the word before and after the newly created gap, and try to train a model to correctly predict the missing word. The result of a model such as this is a word embedding.

Embeddings are numerical representation of words. Using these numerical representations, we can calculate the distance or similarity between two words or sentences. The common method for this is to calculate the cosine similarity of two embedding vectors.

I'm not certain about PMI with spaCy but you can calculate semantic similarity in spaCy using the method I described above.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc1 = nlp('assisted living communities near me')
doc2 = nlp('list of assisted living facilities')
doc3 = nlp('free puppy and kitty adoption')
print(doc1.similarity(doc2))    # 0.8091
print(doc1.similarity(doc3))    # 0.4659
```

Comment: You know what, you got me thinking. I'm going go with this approach and if it works, I'll mark your's as the right answer